# Función para calcular test Chi en varias variables sin repetir el test para cada una de ellas en R

Tags: r, funciones

Necesito hacer una función que me realice pruebas de chisq.test para diferentes tablas de contigencia. Tengo 11 variables (P1a, P1b, P1c, etc) que asumen valor 0 o 1 (mis variables dependientes) y una variable independiente (Nivel) que puede asumir "Alto", "Medio" o "Bajo". Quiero calcular el chi cuadrado para cada una de las variables dependientes con mi variable independiente. Que me realice la siguiente prueba en bucle y me imprima el resultado para cada una de las pruebas realizadas.

```
Prueba <- chisq.test(table(df$P1a,df$Nivel))
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes la información en un `data.frame` puedes aplicar un `lappy` para que haga las comparaciones.

```
df <- data.frame(y=rbinom(30,2,0.5),
           x=replicate(11,rbinom(30,1,0.3))) %>% 
  mutate(y=case_when(y==0~"1. bajo",
                     y==1~"2. medio",
                     y==2~"3. alto"))

lapply(1:11, function(x) chisq.test(table(df[,1],df[,x+1])))
```